How did Jang end up working for Jeonseung?
Apparently, at some point (shortly after?)

 being attacked by Maeda's soldiers and given a Najin, thus transforming him into a monster

Jang starting working for Jeonseung Biotech.

and thus for Maeda, or perhaps for Maeda directly.

A priori, deciding to work for the people responsible for trying to kill him, killing his closest friends, and turning him into a monster is a somewhat counterintuitive decision. Maeda and her accomplices also don't seem to simply be able to control anyone who has a Najin, so it is not that.
So why did he do this?
